# How to clear intermediate activities in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Flows for my screens are:

Activities:
AppHome -> A - > B -> C -> Z

Trying to solve use case:
When I create the activity Z from C -> finish activities C & B.

Expectation:
Pressing back button from  Z should land user on Activity A.

My solutions (which did not work)

Launch Activity B in a new stack (use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK). When launching activity Z, use finishAffinity() on Activity C. Expecting that the new stack will be gone leaving behind previous stack: Home -> Activity A.
However, pressing back button from Z closes the App.

I also tried to use finishAndRemoveTask() on Activity C when launching Z but seems like doing nothing. Any suggestions?

PS: I don't want to finish B when jumping to C since need to provide back navigation there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible way it is uses [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) from androidx. You will have backstack with activities and fragments that allow you to control where return when back button pressed via popup methods to previous destination in the graph.